# Get a different random number within a SCSS for loop

Tags: for-loop, random, sass

I am trying to generate a random number upon each iteration of a for loop in SCSS, however it simply returns the same number on DOM load for all elements targeted within the loop. Im pretty sure my syntax is correct, but clearly not!

**Premise: I am building a brick wall and applying a different brick texture/image to each brick via the SCSS loop. I am attempting to apply a random background image for 16 elements with a potential of 6 background images to choose from. My SASS is version 3.4.14.**

**
scss -v
Sass 3.4.14 (Selective Steve)
**

```css
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  &.front:nth-child(#{$i}), &.back:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    $brick-bg: '../image/brick' + random(6) + '.jpg';
    background-image: url($brick-bg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. I am trying to get a random number each time the for loop executes, not just on page load. The answer you have linked to is only for one URL, i am attempting to do it for 16 elements with a potential 6 background images to choose from. Also, my SASS is version 3.4.14.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible then (was 4, 1, 6, 5, 6, 6 when I ran it):  http://sassmeister.com/gist/daf0e3730647439df2a6

Comment: hmmm, tht is odd! Im running my development through a gulp task, gulp-ruby-sass to be precise. No errors in terminal when compiling either. Very odd. I will raise on the github (https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues) issues page. Please can you kindly remove your indication that this is a duplicate question? Thanks

Comment: The only reason to reopen this question would be to close it as "not reproducible" (can't change the closure reason after the fact).  If you can figure out how to consistently reproduce it, then I can reopen it.